# Python IDLE doesn't work because python.exe is missing

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10, python-idle

When I try to open .py files with IDLE (right click and "edit with IDLE"), Windows will ask whether to use `python.exe` to open this file. If I choose python, IDLE won't start properly.

If I use "open with" and navigate to `Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat` I'll get an error:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib....\pythonw.exe

If I start IDLE from start menu, Windows will open the installer and say `"Please wait while Windows configures Python 2.7.13 (64-bit)"` and if I have the Python installation file available, it will say `"Error writing to file C:\Python27\pythonw.exe"`.

Starting IDLE from CMD (eg. >>`python.exe C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py`) works normally.

I don't see `pythonw.exe` under `C:\Python27\`. Should it be there and how would it delete itself?

I'm using Windows 10 and this issue started a while back. I did a complete reinstall of python and packages and the issue was fixed for a short while, but it returned today.

Comment: I can't comment on how it's disappearing, but can confirm that `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe` should exist.

Comment: Thank you. I ran the python installer and selected repair, the pythonw.exe file is now back and everything seems to work. So the issue is then how this file miraculously stops existing.

Comment: I think it is going to be difficult to diagnose until we have some sort of clue as to what you do around the time it disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've installed Process Monitor and set up filters to monitor the Python folder. Turns out Avast has been busy deleting `pythonw.exe`for a couple of months now.

It happened sparsely in the beginning, but last 12 deletes were from the past few days.

FIXED